# The list function for an object is not working after I add data to object

Tags: grails, groovy

In my `index` action of a controller, I still have the code that is auto-generated when executing the `create-controller` command in Grails. After I add data to object in another action, the `list` method on the domain object no longer works.

The index function:

```
def index(Integer max) {
    params.max = Math.min(max ?: 10, 100)
    respond Worksheet.list(params), model:[worksheetInstanceCount: Worksheet.count()]
}
```

The action I believe is causing the issue:

```
def addResults(Map results,id) {
    def sql = new Sql(dataSource)
    sql.execute("""update domain set results=? where id=?""",new JsonBuilder(results).toString(), id)
}
```

This data is being saved into the database as a `clob`. There are other places where I update that specific domain object just like that, except all I am updating is an integer in the database.

The list action now throws the error Message: `argument type mismatch`

Here is the stacktrace:

```
Error |
2015-11-20 23:14:47,165 [http-bio-8080-exec-2] ERROR property.BasicPropertyAccessor  - HHH000123: IllegalArgumentException in class: com.ABET.Results, setter method of property: r_id
Error |
2015-11-20 23:14:47,166 [http-bio-8080-exec-2] ERROR property.BasicPropertyAccessor  - HHH000091: Expected type: int, actual value: java.lang.String
Error |
2015-11-20 23:14:47,172 [http-bio-8080-exec-2] ERROR errors.GrailsExceptionResolver  - IllegalArgumentException occurred when processing request: [GET] /ABET/worksheet/index
argument type mismatch. Stacktrace follows:
Message: argument type mismatch
    Line | Method
->>   43 | <init>     in grails.orm.PagedResultList
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|     17 | $tt__index in com.ABET.WorksheetController
|    198 | doFilter . in grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.PageFragmentCachingFilter
|     63 | doFilter   in grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.AbstractFilter
|     53 | doFilter . in grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.filter.GrailsAnonymousAuthenticationFilter
|     62 | doFilter   in grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.authentication.logout.MutableLogoutFilter
|   1145 | runWorker  in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    615 | run        in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    744 | run . . .  in java.lang.Thread
```

Comment: Define 'no longer works'; are you seeing any errors? blank page? incorrect results?

Comment: The list function now throws the error Message: argument type mismatch

Answer (score 2):

Assuming `addResults()` is the culprit, try using gorm instead of Groovy's `Sql`.

```
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional
...
@Transactional
def addResults(Map results, int id) {
    def instance = Domain.get(id)
    instance.results = new JsonBuilder(results).toString()
    instance.save()
}
```

Notice that in your example `id` doesn't have a type.

Comment: I used that function and it saved the results, but when I try to use that function again, I still get the same error as well as on the index page

Comment: Add a stacktrace to your question.

Comment: I attached the stacktrace

Comment: @JustinFoley Try removing the old records that might be junk.

Comment: More context is needed to solve this. The stacktrace points to line 17 in `com.ABET.WorksheetController` and something in the `com.ABET.Results` class.

Answer (score 0):

To fix this, I just removed one of the tables that I was using to store data and moved that data to the domain object that I was having issues with.